# Get from name in asp.net masterpage for javascript in sub-page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net website that uses masterpages.  I am trying to use jquery to validate some fields in my subpage.  But jquery wants to know the name of the form.  As you know, the form is created on the masterpage.  I have been unable to get the form in my javascript in the subpage.

I tried to use:

```
var form = $('<%= form1.ClientID %>');
```

But it will not even launch the page from Visual Studio because it says form1 does not exist.  So I moved that line into the masterpage hoping the form variable would still be in scope for my javascript in the subpage.  I will past some of my code below.  Any help on how I can do this would be great.

MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myMaster.master.cs" Inherits="myMaster" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mymain.css" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</head>
<body class="no-sidebar">
    <form runat="server" id="myMaster">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <!-- Main Wrapper -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var form = $('<%= masterForm.ClientID %>');
        });
        </script>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BottomPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Sub-Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="myMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="subpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="subpage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jforms.css">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<div class="wrapper wrapper-640">
    Validate Me.
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BottomPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(form);
        });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: If You see page source, You'll realize, in case of master/content page, form name/id became `aspnetForm`, instead `form1`... every control will get prefixes in id's but form name will be changed.

Comment: Ok, how do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused between a Master page and content page. Basically content page sits inside the master page mark-up i.e. when the HTML is rendered to the browser it contains the html of master page and inside that the html of content page. This means that when you write your `jQuery` code in content page you will have the `form` tag defined in master page available in the content page itself.

Now, suppose you have a label control in your content page like this:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Hello"></asp:Label>
```

And you want to fetch it's text, So in your content page you can say:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var myMasterForm = $("#myMaster");
     var msg = $("#<%= lblTest.ClientID %>", form).text();
     alert(msg);   //Output: Hello
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I do fully understand how the Master page/Content page relationship/rendering works.

Here's my question for your code: if I put "#myMaster", won't it not be the same as the name that get's rendered?

Comment: @MichaelPoznecki - Yes it's the same name that is the reason we are selecting it with jQuery. It will work just fine, let me know if I am not clear.